# How to write scope with association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

Could you help me write following scope:

`Cv` belongs_to `Student` and I want to write scope which gives me all cvs where student has at least one 
 education(`student.edcuations.any?`) and student is valid(have all attributes filled)

I want to write that scope for `Cv`.

*Models*

```
#cv.rb
belongs_to :student

#student.rb
has_many :cvs
has_many :educations
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'm misunderstanding the layout of your models.

I feel like it should look more like this, since each CV would have an education listed (otherwise, how are the connected to each other in the database)

```
#cv.rb
belongs_to :student
has_many :educations

#student.rb
has_many :cvs

#education.rb
belongs_to :cvs
```

I'd probably just use a class method though.

```
#student.rb
def cvs_with_education
   self.cvs.reject {|cv| cv.educations.empty?}
end
```

Comment: Students has many educations because education contain his department and faculties. And Student can have many educations. I am sure about that.

Comment: Ah, Thats fair, I misunderstood the point of the education table (by lack of information). 

Are you trying to return all cvs for all students that have one education defined, or just Cvs for one student with at least one education?

Comment: For all students, thats why I thought about scopes

Answer (score 0):

Check out section 11.2.3 of the [ActieRecord Query Interface Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) for how to join nested associations.

Something like

```
scope :with_education, joins(:student => :educations).where("some conditions")
```

You probably want to define a `:valid_student` scope and then leverage that within.

Comment: Is better way for valid_student that check each attribute? ``scope :with_valid_student, joins(:student).where('first_name IS NOT NULL AND first_name IS NOT NULL AND email IS NOT NULL (...etc...)')``

Comment: Well first I would ask myself if invalid students should exist in the database in the first place. Maybe you should add validations to the Student class so that only valid records can be created. That aside, the answer is pretty much no. The ActiveRecord 'where' method is rather limited. There are gems that give you more power though. Take a look at MetaWhere.